# iPad 6th Gen shows white background login screen after power on, but no keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, touch-id

This has been occurring for some time now, spanning several iOS updates, now to the latest 16.1.1. It is more of an inconvenience, but I would like to know if anybody else has seen this problem, (and perhaps has a solution.)

I power on the iPad, it shows me the booting Apple logo in black, with a white background, then presents me with the expected "Enter Passcode - Touch ID requires your passcode when iPad restarts" message and a passcode field. The message and Passcode field are showing but there is *no keyboard* to tap in the passcode. There is no invisible keyboard lurking at the bottom of the screen, either.

To proceed to login, I must toggle the power button to come back to the login screen wallpaper, then press the Home button to invoke the login screen which appears now with a black background, the "Enter Passcode" message as above, a passcode field and the keyboard. The black background will also appear if I let the login screen sleep, (it times out after 5 seconds,) and press the Home button to wake.

- The system Light/Dark mode setting is not an issue here: it occurs
  when either is enabled.
- Touch ID works as expected after login. When
  I temporarily disable Unlocking using Touch ID, after a restart the login message is the same as above, without the Touch ID qualifier. The background is still white, and there is no keyboard.

Any clues to what may be going on here?

Comment: Yes, this happens to me too, I'm doing the same thing as you are...